# Angular2 Get value from Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How Can I get value from this array? I would like to take from each of Object value as firstPersonName.

[image]

I wrote something like this

```
var rest = email.map(a => {
    a.firstPersonEmail;
});
console.log(rest);
```

But i am getting

[image]

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 3):

This may help you:

```
var rest = email.map(a => {
  return a.firstPersonEmail;
});
console.log(rest);
```

or

```
var rest = email.map(a => a.firstPersonEmail);
console.log(rest);
```

```js
const email = [
  {id:1, firstPersonEmail: "John@mail.mail"},
  {id:2, firstPersonEmail: "John2@mail.mail"},
  {id:3, firstPersonEmail: "John3@mail.mail"}
];

const emptyEmail = [];

console.log(`Email length: ${email.length}`);
console.log(`Empty Email length: ${emptyEmail.length}`);

const rest = email.map(a => a.firstPersonEmail);
const emptyRest = emptyEmail.map(a => a.firstPersonEmail);

console.log(rest);
console.log(emptyRest);
```

Comment: Bro, You have to add `return` in the callback function but your question don't have `return` :P

Comment: It doesn't work with return as well :( The result is the same :(

Comment: So I don't know why it still doesn't work. You might double check your array object. You may try `console.log(email.length)` It should return 2

Comment: It's returning 0. So it's not Array?

Comment: That makes sense, it's exactly array and it's empty array. when use `map`   with empty array only return empty array. Please make sure the `email`  contains any data. And also you can try to run code snippet in edited answer.

Comment: Email's data are shown on picture. :( Hmmm I run it, will try to fix it :( Anyway thanks :)